# Возврат пустого объекта из метода в классе

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть некий класс **MyClass** вынесенный в отдельный *js* файл **my-class.js** который собирает информацию с сайта и помещает результат в некий объект **allNews** из метода **parametrs**. Затем из другого файла **index.js** нужно получить тот самый объект с данными, но при деструктуризации получаю сообщение **undefined** тоесть объект почему-то пустой, хотя если попробовать вывести этот объекта в самом методе то данные туда попадают. В чем я допустил ошибку ?

> Хорошо если я правильно понимаю я изменил код добавив асинхроность но результат пока прежний. Получается в моём случае async/await мне не подходит ?
>
> Код из файла **my-class.js**

```
module.exports = class NewsScrap { 
    constructor(urls){
         this.urls = urls;
     } 
    async parametrs (){
        const allNews = {
                allHeader: [],
                allText: [],
                allUrl: {
                url: []
 }
};
  /* Тут код scraping'a который собирает данные и после передает в обект */
  allNews.allText.push(text);
  allNews.allHeader.push(haider);
  allNews.allUrl.url.push(urlLastNews);   
  return await allNews;
 };
};
```

> Код из файла **index.js**

```
const NewsScrap = require ("./news-scraping");
(async function(){
        const news = await new NewsScrap("https://site.ru/news/game/").parametrs();
        const {allHeader, allText} = news;
        console.log(await allHeader);
}); ();
```

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо за пометку, но проблема осталась прежней даже с добавлением **async/await**. Либо я чего-то недопонимаю

Comment: потому что ты их не туда добавил. Посмотри в вопросе дубликате - куда должны добавляться данные ключевые слова. Там даже есть пример.